# xamarin forms -- detect external bluetooth 'turn on' and toggle 'switch' accordingly in the app

Tags: c#, xamarin, bluetooth, switch-statement, toggle

Is there a way to make an app read  bluetooth activation from external trigger for example when a user swipes down the screen and turns it on and toggle the switch accordingly in the app(i.e if the user externally turns it on so should my switch auto toggle itself to on and vice versa).
Here is the xamarin C# code i use to switch bluetooth on and off in my app.
MainActivity.cs

```
void Enable(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            BluetoothManager _manager;
            _manager = (BluetoothManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.BluetoothService);
            bool on = _manager.Adapter.IsEnabled;
            if (on == true)
            {
                string error = "Bluetooth is Already on";
                Toast.MakeText(this, error, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                e.Equals(true);
            }
            else
            {
                string okay = "Bluetooth has been turned on";
                _manager.Adapter.Enable();
                Toast.MakeText(this, okay, ToastLength.Long).Show();

            }
        }
 void Disable(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            BluetoothManager _manager;
            _manager = (BluetoothManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.BluetoothService);
            bool on = _manager.Adapter.IsEnabled;
            if (on == false)
            {
                string error = "Bluetooth is Already off";
                Toast.MakeText(this, error, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                e.Equals(false);
               
            }
            else
            {
                string okay = "Bluetooth has been turned off";
                _manager.Adapter.Disable();
                Toast.MakeText(this, okay, ToastLength.Long).Show();

            }
        }
```

The subscriber Messaging Center i used in the mainactivity is this one

```
  BluetoothAndroid();
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, bool>(this, "Bluetooth", (sender, isEnabled) =>
            {
                if (isEnabled)
                {
                    Enable(null, new EventArgs());
                }
                else
                {
                    Disable(null, new EventArgs());
                }
            });
```

and the MainPage.xaml.cs Subscriber.sender method is

```
 private  void Enable(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e) {
            if (e.Value == true)
            {
                MessagingCenter.Send<object, bool>(this, "Bluetooth", true);
               // await DisplayAlert("Bluetooth Status", "Bluetooth has been turned on", "OK");

            }
            else
            {
                MessagingCenter.Send<object, bool>(this, "Bluetooth", false);
               // await DisplayAlert("Bluetooth Status", "Bluetooth has been turned off", "OK");
            }
        }
```

All i need is C sharp code to get into the ART, derive the state and set the toggle of the switch to be either on or off when the user triggers state from external activity, Thank You

Comment: Are there any update for this issue?

Comment: No his class didnt show any errors but am still not able to turn on Bluetooth from external trigger

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `BroadcastReceiver` listening for the `android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED` action and act accordingly.

```cs
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new[] { BluetoothAdapter.ActionStateChanged })]
public class BluetoothStateChangedReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.Extras == null)
            return;

        var state = intent.GetIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.ExtraState, -1);

        switch(state)
        {
            case (int)State.On:
                // bluetooth is on
                break;
            case (int)State.Off:
                // bluetooth is off
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to instantiate and register your receiver, a good place would be your MainActivity.

Comment: Thanks so much @CheeseBaron, lemme implement it, i will be right back with feedback